# libtorrent new piece alerts

Tags: libtorrent, libtorrent-rasterbar

I am developing an application that will stream multimedia files over torrents.

The backend needs to serve new pieces to the frontend as they arrive.

I need a mechanism to get notified when new pieces have arrived and been verified. From what I can tell, I could do this using `block_finished_alert`s. I would keep track of which blocks have arrived for a given piece, and read the piece when all blocks have arrived.

This solution seems kind of roundabout and I was wondering if there was a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're asking for is called `piece_finished_alert`. It's posted every time a new piece completes downloading and passes the hash-check. To read a piece from disk, you may use `torrent_handle::read_piece()` (and get the result in `read_piece_alert`).

However, if you want to stream media, you probably want to use `torrent_handle::set_piece_deadline()` and set the flag to send `read_piece_alerts` as pieces come in. This will invoke the built-in streaming feature of libtorrent.